# why do ggplot2 95%CI and prediction 95%CI calculated manually differ?

Tags: r, ggplot2, lme4, mixed-models, confidence-interval

I'd like to know why when calculating 95% confidence bands from a linear mixed effects model does ggplot2 produces narrower bands than when calculated manually, e.g. by following Ben Bolker's method here [confidence intervals on predictions](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#lme4). That is, is ggplot2 giving an inaccurate representation of the model?

Here is a reproducible example using the sleepstudy dataset (modified to be structurally similar to a df that I'm working on):

```
data("sleepstudy") # load dataset 
height <- seq(165, 185, length.out = 18) # create vector called height
Treatment <- rep(c("Control", "Drug"), 9) # create vector called treatment
Subject <- levels(sleepstudy$Subject) # get vector of Subject
ht.subject <- data.frame(height, Subject, Treatment) 
sleepstudy <- dplyr::left_join(sleepstudy, ht.subject, by="Subject") # Append df so that each subject has its own height and treatment
sleepstudy$Treatment <- as.factor(sleepstudy$Treatment)
```

Generate model, add predictions to original df, and plot

```
m.sleep <- lmer(Reaction ~ Treatment*height + (1 + Days|Subject), data=sleepstudy)
sleepstudy$pred <- predict(m.sleep)
ggplot(sleepstudy, aes(height, pred, col=Treatment)) + geom_smooth(method="lm")[2]
```

Calculate confidence intervals following Bolker method

```
newdf <- expand.grid(height=seq(165, 185, 1),
                   Treatment=c("Control","Drug"))
newdf$Reaction <- predict(m.sleep, newdf, re.form=NA) 
modmat <- model.matrix(terms(m.sleep), newdf)
pvar1 <- diag(modmat %*% tcrossprod(vcov(m.sleep), modmat))
tvar1 <- pvar1+VarCorr(m.sleep)$Subject[1]
cmult <- 1.96

newdf <- data.frame(newdf
,plo = newdf$Reaction-cmult*sqrt(pvar1)
,phi = newdf$Reaction+cmult*sqrt(pvar1)
,tlo = newdf$Reaction-cmult*sqrt(tvar1)
,thi = newdf$Reaction+cmult*sqrt(tvar1))

# plot confidence intervals
ggplot(newdf, aes(x=height, y=Reaction, colour=Treatment)) + 
geom_point() +
geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=plo, ymax=phi, fill=Treatment), alpha=0.4)[2]
```

Comment: This might be a good Q for stats.stackexchange.com.  After skimming your code and the linked GitHub for just a minute:  does Bolker's method generate _confidence_ intervals around predictions, or _prediction_ intervals?  Most stats software distinguishes between the two.

Comment: I think it's for generating confidence intervals around predictions, but perhaps I am mistaken on this. And I'll do as you suggest and repost on stats.stackexchange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a few tweaks, this seems consistent. The confidence intervals are indeed larger, but not enormously much larger. Keep in mind that ggplot is fitting a **very** different model; it is fitting separate linear (not linear mixed) models by treatment that ignore (1) repeated measures and (2) the effect of day.

It seems weird to fit a model with random slopes but no population-level slope (e.g.see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/199377/is-it-reasonable-to-include-a-random-slope-term-in-an-lmer-model-without-the-cor)), so I added a fixed effect of `Days`:

```
m.sleep <- lmer(Reaction ~ Treatment*height + Days +
                (1 + Days|Subject),
                data=sleepstudy)
```

I reorganized the plotting code a little bit:

```
theme_set(theme_bw())
gg0 <- ggplot(sleepstudy, aes(height, colour=Treatment)) +
    geom_point(aes(y=Reaction))+
    geom_smooth(aes(y=pred), method="lm")
```

- If you want to compute confidence intervals (which would be comparable with what `lm()`/`ggplot2` is doing), then you probably should *not* add `VarCorr(m.sleep)$Subject[1]` to the variance (the `tvar1` variable  from the [FAQ example](http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#lme4) is for creating **prediction intervals** rather than confidence intervals ...)
- since I had `Days` in the model above, I added `mean(sleepstudy$Days)` to the prediction data frame.

```
newdf <- expand.grid(height=seq(165, 185, 1),
                     Treatment=c("Control","Drug"),
                     Days=mean(sleepstudy$Days))
newdf$Reaction <- newdf$pred <- predict(m.sleep, newdf, re.form=NA) 
modmat <- model.matrix(terms(m.sleep), newdf)
pvar1 <- diag(modmat %*% tcrossprod(vcov(m.sleep), modmat))
tvar1 <- pvar1
cmult <- 1.96

newdf <- data.frame(newdf
,plo = newdf$Reaction-cmult*sqrt(pvar1)
,phi = newdf$Reaction+cmult*sqrt(pvar1)
,tlo = newdf$Reaction-cmult*sqrt(tvar1)
,thi = newdf$Reaction+cmult*sqrt(tvar1))

gg0 + 
    geom_point(data=newdf,aes(y=Reaction)) +
    geom_ribbon(data=newdf,
                aes(ymin=plo, ymax=phi, fill=Treatment), alpha=0.4,
                colour=NA)
```

[image]

Comparing with the estimated slopes and standard errors:

```
m0 <- lm(Reaction~height*Treatment,sleepstudy)
ff <- function(m) {
    print(coef(summary(m))[-1,c("Estimate","Std. Error")],digits=2)
}

> ff(m0)
##                      Estimate Std. Error
## height                   -0.3       0.94
## TreatmentDrug          -602.2     234.01
## height:TreatmentDrug      3.5       1.34

ff(m.sleep)
##                      Estimate Std. Error
## TreatmentDrug          -55.03      425.3
## height                   0.41        1.7
## Days                    10.47        1.5
## TreatmentDrug:height     0.33        2.4
```

This looks consistent/about right: the mixed model is giving larger standard errors for the slope with respect to height and the height:treatment interaction. (The main effects of `TreatmentDrug` look crazy because they're the expected effects of treatment at `height==0` ...)

---

As a cross-check, I can get similar answers from `sjPlot::plot_model()` ...

```
library(sjPlot)
plot_model(m.sleep, type="pred", terms=c("height","Treatment"))
```

[image]